# string parsing {{var}}/text{{var}}

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing

I need parse follow string `const input = '{{var}}/text{{var}}'` result must be follow 
`const result = ['{{var}}', '/text', '{{var}}']`. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything ?

Comment: @Zyigh yes, now have next regex `/{{\/?[^}}]+}}/g` I tried add something else to find part whithout `{{}}` but nothing helped me

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: `"someTextWhichPossiblyContains{Or}...{{the}Desired{Text}}And{Some}}Remaining{Text".match(/\{\{(?:(?!\}\}).)*\}\}/);`

Comment: @ASDFGerte thanks by help but it's not exactly what I want

Comment: answer is `/{{?[^}}]+}}|}?[^{]+/g`

Answer (score 0):

You will need a function to replace the text but i think the regex you want is [`({{\w+}})(\/\w+)({{\w+}})`](https://regex101.com/r/erkTGx/1). This provides the parts in the groups 1-3 so you can format them how you like. You probably also want to add a check to make sure part 1 is the same as part 3 to avoid mismatched pairs.

```
function replace(str) {
    let matches = str.match(/({{\w+}})(\/\w+)({{\w+}})/);
    return str.replace(/({{\w+}})(\/\w+)({{\w+}})/, `['${matches[1]}', '${matches[2]}', '${matches[3]}']`);
}
replace("const input = '{{var}}/text{{var}}'"); // "const input = '['{{var}}', '/text', '{{var}}']'"
```